# USART echo using python

Tags: python

I connect RX and TX of USART to USB converter directly, and using GtkTerm I am watching output. I am using this piece of python code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial (port = "/dev/ttyUSB0", bytesize = 8, stopbits = 1)
ser.baudrate = 115200                   
ser.write('\x41') # A
ser.close()
```

And my output in GtkTerm is:

```
A
```

But I expect, because RX and TX are connected directly:

```
AA
```

Is my assumption right?

Comment: Why you expect such output?

Comment: I am not sure, but if I send 'A' to serial port (it appears there once), and if RX is connected with TX, it should appear in GtkTerm again, or not?

Comment: If you send `A`, it will be stored in the Transmit Buffer for Transmission...but since Tx is connected to Rx, it will be received into the Receive Buffer...and then Displayed in `GtkTerm`...so I don't see how you expect to get `AA`

Comment: Ok, now I understand, thank you for an explanation.